# CUDA NSIGHT: call an unmatched malloc or an unmatched free

Tags: cuda, nsight

I am unable to understand the following statement in the [NSIGHT user Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/profile_cuda_settings.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%2520Tools%7CDesktop%2520Developer%2520Tools%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%7CNVIDIA%2520Nsight%2520Visual%2520Studio%2520Edition%25204.1%7CAnalysis%2520Tools%7CCUDA%2520Experiments%7C_____0)

**Non-Overlapping Input/Output Buffers**

```
a kernel can malloc and free a buffer in the same launch, 
but it cannot call an unmatched malloc or an unmatched free.
```

Can someone explain it a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means that you shouldn't `malloc` or `free` *across* different kernel launches. 
If you `malloc` during a kernel launch, you **must** `free` it during the *same* launch, not several launches later.

This is only required if you enable the NSIGHT profiler option `Non-Overlapping Input/Output Buffers`, as it allows the profiler to perform some optimizations. If you *do* `malloc` or `free` across kernel launches (which is perfectly fine as far as CUDA is concerned), then simply disable that option.

Comment: will there be any compilation/run-time error when I call malloc() and free accross different launches ?

Comment: If your kernel meets the requirements listed then the profiler does not have to save and restore all mutable state between kernel replays. If the kernel has an unmatched malloc or free then the profiler has to save and restore the device heap. For example if the kernel malloced 1MB each launch and it did not free and if the profiler did not restore the heap allocator then each replay would malloc an additional 1MB. If the profiler takes N passes then it will leak (N-1) × 1MB of device heap.